# Using Android Voice Control launch my Activity

Tags: android, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, android-hardware

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316937/how-can-i-use-speech-recognition-without-the-annoying-dialog-in-android-phones) post on SO and I have tried the code to launch my own speech recognition activity. It worked!. So my question is that how can I customize the action of the built in voice command button(hardware) to launch the activity which I have written instead of the built in voice search? I have thoroughly searched the net including [this](http://www.askvg.com/google-android-hidden-secret-codes/) website. But I could not find a solution. I know that someone on SO has it!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `SpeechRecognizer` instead of `RecognizerIntent`. It's a little harder to use, but you get full control.

For code see my response from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9625045/speech-recognition-help/9631708#9631708):

and my discussion of the differences between the two approaches [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10223490/)

Comment: But my question is"how can I customize the action of the built in voice command button(hardware) to launch the activity which I have written instead of the built in voice search?"

Comment: I'm not sure. I think Google controls that button.