# How to open Activity based on the voice command

Tags: android, voice, voice-recognition

I am doing dashboard application in which there are lot of screens. When the user tell the voice command based on that I need to open the activity. I don't know where to start I have already completed all the screens and I would like to implement voice search.
my app screens are Advances, Leaves, Recruitment, Permissions, Notifications etc
Example: when the user say 'Advances' it should open the advances screens. Please help me.

Comment: i think this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html will help you

Comment: I want to start activity based on the voice command...already I have implemented search...thanks for your reply

Comment: When i google your question i get this http://stackoverflow.com/a/10330292/1697047. Just go through this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Start a voice recognition intent

2) Handle the returned data in onActivityResult() to decide which activity to start

**1. Start a voice recognition intent**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Choose Activity");
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SPEECH);
```

**2. Handle the returned data**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_SPEECH){
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                ArrayList<String> matches = data
                    .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

                if (matches.size() == 0) {
                    // didn't hear anything
                } else {
                    String mostLikelyThingHeard = matches.get(0);
                    // toUpperCase() used to make string comparison equal
                    if(mostLikelyThingHeard.toUpperCase().equals("ADVANCES")){
                        startActivity(new Intent(this, Advances.class));
                    } else if() {
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for Sharing info @jfortunato . i wanted to pass intent to my Contact List instead of "ADVANCES". i tried it but not getting it, as for passing Intent to Contact List again i should use a method startActivityForResult() instead of startActivity(). Will you please help me out?