# Open activity on voice command only

Tags: android, voice

App to be used in hands free with voice command to open activities. There may or may not be internet access so can not rely on it for voice recognition.

Looked at a very large number of examples but they appear to need internet. If there is a good tutorial out there I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

One result of this will be brainless motions making comments,

Comment: I think you might be looking for something like [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40652373/offline-google-voice-recognition-on-android)

Comment: I think you're looking for this one only [How to open Activity based on the voice command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14433105/7108030)

Comment: Hi Vinoth, Tried this on but kept getting error on REQUEST_SPEECH part. Also from text with what I think is the original posting you have to be connected to internet.