# How to add a Speech recognition button in my Android App?

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I am a Java Developer. Sorry I have 0 Idea on Android. Please bear with me.

I am thinking of creating an app. To build my app first I must learn must learn android. To get the motivation I am trying to Sketch the app, how it should look like. I thought of making my app hands free, meaning that I want to use Speech Recognition for navigation and performing all the tasks.

Now my question is "Is there any way I can add the Google's Speech recognizer to my App as a Custom Button?" So it will not take half the screen it will just listen at the end of the screen. I will convert the audio into a text file so, I can use API.AI to do some stuff behind it.

Or there any other ways to achieve my goal?

Can the google speech recognizer work on iOS too?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Speech Recognition Android App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9625045/speech-recognition-android-app)

Answer (score 1):

You can use android SpeechRecognizer.Check out the link for the implementations: Visit https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html

I tried SpecchRecognizer in one of my project.

First  You have to implement your activity like this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements RecognitionListener
```

Then do below code in your OnClickListener.

```
SpeechRecognizer speech = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
                 speech.setRecognitionListener(this);
                 intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
                 intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                         RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
                 intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "en-US");
                 intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, this.getPackageName());
                 speech.startListening(intent);
```

In OnActivityResult You can get the result.

```
ArrayList<String> result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
textview.setText(result.get(0));
```

You can also get below implemenations.you can do whatever you want in the  below override methods.

```
@Override
public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {

}

@Override
public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {

}

@Override
public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {

}

@Override
public void onEndOfSpeech() {

}

@Override
public void onError(int error) {

}
@Override
public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {

}
```

That's all.